# Can a Uchiha get their sharingan back from an implant?

Tags: naruto

If a sharingan user/Uchiha gave someone their sharingan, would they be able to take it back and put it in their eye socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kakashi and Danzo got their Sharingan via transplantation while the fourth great ninja war was ongoing, then Madara removed Obito's Sharingan from Kakashi's left eye and was able to implant it into his and utilize it.